# How do I disable the formatting symbols in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I actually can't see anything because of all the formatting symbols. I have no idea what hotkey that was but I can't find any solution how to disable those symbols. Have you any idea if there is a hotkey? I can't remember what that hotkey was ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the hotkey: ctrl + '.' (period)

But that depend of your hotkey profile.

Answer (score 69):

You can also disable them by using this button:
[image]

Comment: I shows up when you're viewing certain file types. It shows up for .java files for me, but not for .xml files. The effect of toggling the button for one file seems to apply to all editors, regardless of file type. Too lazy to investigate a general solution... :P

Comment: The general solution is to open a file of the type where you want to show the button for (a *.xml file) then: Window > Perspective > Customize Perspective.

Then on the 3rd tab (Action Set Availability) select the "Editor Presentation" so it becomes active.

You can remove all "Editor Presentation" icons except "Show Whitespace Characters" in the first tab (Tool Bar Visibility): expand "Editor Presentation" and then unselect all icons except for "Show Whitespace Characters"

Answer (score 38):

The command you are looking for is "Show Whitespace Characters". If you cannot find it in the toolbar or menu, the simplest way to disable it is:

- press <Ctrl>-3
- enter "Show Whitespace Characters"
- select the command from the list with a double click or hitting

Answer (score 8):

You can turn off/enable white spaces/line break by:

Window > Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors > 'Show whitespace characters'

Answer (score 2):

You can on/off white spaces and line breaks the following step in eclipse.

Window →　Editor →　Show WhiteSpace Characters

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also disable them by using button showing in below image:

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).