# Getting weird symbols in the Eclipse IDE that I can't highlight or delete

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, symbols

I've been getting these weird symbols all of a sudden. I'm assuming I accidently turned something on but I'm unsure what it is. Any help would be apprecitated.

The picture of the problem: [Imgur picture for the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4B9S.png)

Comment: These are spacing signs that tell you what kind of whitespaces you used. You can turn them off. For example >> means you used the tabulator. None of them affect the syntax of your code.

Comment: @G. Bach: "None of them affect the syntax of your code". Depends on the language. For Java, yes. But for other languages like Python or Coffeescript, they are pretty important.

Comment: @Thilo Given that the tags exclusively mention Java, I omitted that; but you're right, of course.

Answer (score 39):

Look for this button:
[image]
and disable it.

Comment: +1. Been using Eclipse for ten years, never noticed that button. Always dig through preferences. Please also post this answer on the linked duplicate question.

Comment: Really I am also using long time onwards eclipse but I never marked this symbol.

Answer (score 11):

You've accidentally set Eclipse to show whitespace. You can fix it here:

```
Window >> Preferences >> General >> Editors >> Text Editors:
  [x] Show whitespace characters
```

Answer (score 4):

That is "visible whitespace". Shows tabs, spaces, and line breaks.

In Preferences, Go to General > Editors > Text Editors and uncheck "show whitespace characters".

Answer (score 0):

Those are whitespace symbols.  The hotkey for disabling them is `CTRL .` (that's a period).

This question was also answered here, but I'm not sure we should mark as duplicate.
[How do I disable the formatting symbols in eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957634/how-do-i-disable-the-formatting-symbols-in-eclipse)

Comment: Yes you can close it now, since it is a duplicate and everyone will just see that one anyways. I was just unsure what they were called so I couldn't google it.

Comment: @user2146723 Actually that's exactly why I didn't want to close it; if someone googles these exact words (which is what you thought to type when asking the question), they won't find the other question, but they will find this one :).

Comment: @CoryKendall: You'll find closed questions in Google as well.